# Create a class function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone complete the syntax of a function in a react class component that I want in order to press the onClick event and if the credentials are true will enter otherwise will give an error! I will post my thinking first:

*Function* with a const user={username: 'gerasimos', password: '27111980'} and then if(this.state.username & this.state.password ===user.password) { this.props.onRouteChange('home')

I have the idea in my head but not sure about the complete syntax.

My code is this:

````
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  handleUserInput = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value})}

  render () {
    return (
    <article className="br2 ba dark-gray b--black-30 mv6 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw5 center">
      <main className="pa4 black-80">
        <div className="measure center">
          <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
            <legend className="f4 fw6 ph0 mh0">Log In</legend>
            <div className="mt3">
              <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="email-address">Email</label>
              <input className="pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                type="email" 
                name="email" 
                id="email-address"
                placeholder="Email"
                value={this.state.email}
                onChange={this.handleUserInput}  
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mv3">
              <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input className="b pa2 input-reset ba bg-transparent hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                type="password" 
                name="password"  
                id="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.handleUserInput}
              />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div className="">
            <input  onClick = {() => this.props.onRouteChange("home")}
              className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
              type="submit" 
              value="Log in" 
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </article>
    );
  }
}```

Thank you in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

[React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) defines event handling beautifully. You should check this out.

In your code, you have `email` and `password` as input fields and not `username` and `password`.

```
<input
  onClick={this.handleOnclick}
  className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-transparent grow pointer f6 dib"
  type="submit"
  value="Log in"
/>
```

This is how you can define the onClick handler.

```
handleOnclick = () => {
  const user = { email: "gerasimos", password: "27111980" };
  if (
    this.state.email === user.email &&
    this.state.password === user.password
  ) {
    this.props.onRouteChange("home");
  }
};
```

Comment: You saved my day! Your answer worked wonderfully!